# Compiling java program filenotfoundexception

Tags: java, exception, compilation, filenotfoundexception

Having trouble compiling my java file and i think the problem lies here: 
Problem faced is that i have to include a filenotfoundexception. however, when i add it in, compiler gives me an error of "overridden method does not throw filenotfoundexception" Any idea on how to solve this?

```
public String getArrival(String flightNumber) {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("flights.txt"));
   while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
      String s = scanner.nextLine();
      if(s.indexOf(flightNumber)!=-1){
         String city = s.split("-")[1];
         System.out.println("getArrival(): " + flightNumber + " ==>     Arrival city is " + city);
         return city;
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the file is not found?

Comment: Can you give us the complete error message, and show us this line the compiler is complaining about?

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the FileNotFoundException yourself using try/catch.

Try this ...

```
Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File("flights.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: *"overridden method does not throw filenotfoundexception"*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly are you doing, but isn't the error quite self-explanatory? `"overridden method does not throw filenotfoundexception"` error will show if you are trying to `catch` something that is not being thrown by any code in your `try` clause.

```
try{
    callMethodThatDoesNotThrowAnException();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
   // if your try clause does not throw any FileNotFoundException, 
   // then this clause will NEVER be executed. 
}
```

On the contrary, if you have a method that throws a `FileNotFoundException`, then you can catch it:

```
    try{
        callMethodThatThrowsFileNotFoundException ();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
       // the exception thrown by the method will be caught here 
    }

private void callMethodThatThrowsFileNotFoundException() throws FileNotFoundException{
    throw new FileNotFoundException ("File not found");
}
```

hope this helps.